# Distorted result with fabric.loadSVGFromString

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I've edited an SVG with inkscape :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg id="svg2816" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48 48" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
 <defs id="defs2818"></defs>
 <metadata id="metadata2821">
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
    <dc:title/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <g id="layer1" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke="#ce3762" stroke-linecap="butt">
  <path id="path2828" style="stroke-dasharray:none;" d="M40,3,35,3,20,18,10,18s-5,5,0,10h10l15,15h5v-40z" transform="translate(-5,0)" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.5" fill="#42101e"/>
  <path id="path2830" d="m37,13s2,7.5359,0,15" transform="translate(0,2)" stroke-width="1px" fill="none"/>
  <path id="path2834" d="m40,11s3,10,0,19" transform="translate(0,2)" stroke-width="1px" fill="none"/>
  <path id="path2836" d="m43,6s6,14,0,29" transform="translate(0,2)" stroke-width="1px" fill="none"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

It should look like this:

[image]

When I import it with fabricjs :

```
// volumeOnPrint is the string pasted before
fabric.loadSVGFromString(volumeOnPrint, function(objects, options) {
    var widget = new fabric.PathGroup(objects, options);
    // root is my fabricjs canvas
    root.add(widget);
});
```

It get that :

[image]

(The background is not the issue, it's the one of my canvas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Fabric.

I just [fixed it and pushed](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/a83b97a4e47f539c602d43de56ba635ce06ba26e) new version (0.9.21).

Generally, SVG files created with Inkscape are harder to parse than those created with Illustrator. But we're getting better and better :)

There's a growing [visual test suite](http://fabricjs.com/svg_rendering/), to which I added your shape to avoid regressions in the future (let me know if that's OK). Careful as it might take a while to load/parse all the shapes.