# Multiple math formulas on Canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, latex

I need to write (complex) math formulas made with Latex on multiple canvases.
I know it's possible to do this for one formula with MathJax: from Latex to SVG to Canvas, see other post
[Write latex formulas in fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721379/write-latex-formulas-in-fabric-js)
and there is also a jsFiddle to do this: see solution above.

BUT: in my program I need multiple dynamically generated formulas on multiple images to drag them around.

(I want to make a much more complex version of this one (made by myself): http://henkreuling.nl/applets/Mini-loco_breuken_met_letters.html; there I manually place the formulas on the canvas by normal canvastext and lines. But that's too difficult for more complex formulas...)

I think because the canvas got 'tainted' after painting the SVG (???), I think it's therefore necessary to use multiple canvases ???
I tried to change the jsFiddle, but whatever I try, I only see one formula.
Must I need multipe canvases, or how can I paint several formulas on one canvas?

Comment: This is just a comment. Why do you need those formulas on canvases? You can let them as svg elements and drag and drop them with the [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)

Comment: Maybe that's possible, but I made an application where the tiles are images, with a complete functionally library... with this I made already a lot of useful apps. To do what you suggest, I should rewrite a lot more... I hope it's possible to just generate images with the formulas, so I can keep the main program and library unchanged.